# JSPlumb: Resize HTML5 Canvas depending on Content

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

So, to explain my scenario: I want to create an online "finite state machine"-webapp which is capable to visualize the automaton-concepts (deterministic, non-deterministic) and later on does some logic like minimizing and so on to help students comprehend these abstract concepts in a way of experimenting around.

So for my views, I thought about JSPlumb as the way to go (other recommendations are appreciated) - but I can't find the option to "resize" the HTML5 Canvas in JSPlumb. For lets say automatons with 100 nodes, a 640x480 canvas wouldn't be very nice, so what it *should* be is, starting with a canvas of 640x480, clicking and dragging on the side of the canvas, the user could extend it to its needs. Sure about that, the previously drawn elements should keep their places.

So, my question is: Is it possible to do this with jsplumb or do I need to code it myself? If I need to code it myself, any hints on where to start changing the jsplumb files would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSPlumb is not using the canvas, as far as I know, it's using SVG or VML on old IE browser.
This problably means that you can resize the SVG object via the appropriate width & height property, but AFAIK, this is not automatic.